# how to use sqlsession to update mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, mybatis

I want to update the mysql database in spring mybatis. I have couple of mapper interface and want to perform update using sqlsession.commit(). How can I define each of sqlsession?

```
@Transactional
public BookingRecord book(Person person, Hotel hotel, String id) {
    List<Room> rooms = hotel.getRooms();
    for (Room room : rooms) {
        if (room.isAvailable()) {
            if (person.getBalance() > room.getPrice()) {

                // 开始订房
                room.setAvailable(false);   // 保留房间
                person.setId(id);
                person.setBalance(person.getBalance() - room.getPrice()); //转账
                hotel.setBalance(hotel.getBalance() + room.getPrice()); //转账2
                BookingRecord r = new BookingRecord(); //生成订单
                r.setHotelName(hotel.getName());    //记录酒店名
                r.setRoomNumber(room.getRoomNumber()); //记录房间号
                r.setPersonId(person.getId()); //记录客人id
                r.setStartDate(new Date());
                personMapper.update(person);
                brMapper.create(r);
                hotelMapper.updateBalance(hotel);
                roomMapper.update(room);
                return r;
            }
        }
    }
    log.info(person.getName() + "successfully booked at " + hotel.getName());
    return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Transactional make this class transactional means spring will manage begin, commit and rollback procedure during executions. Transactions itself is a very wide area of research so I suggest you should read [Spring Transaction](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html) to understand more about how Spring manages transaction. And in regards to your question, I suggest you should inject JDBC connection to this bean to perform begin, (commit or rollback) prophetically.